# PHP - Echo value in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I feel like I am losing my mind.

```
<?php
print_r($roc_option);
?>
```

prints out this:

> Array ( ['class'] => classnew1 ['id'] => idnew1 )

but then, on the next line,

```
<?php
echo $roc_option['class'];
?>
```

prints out NOTHING.

Any ideas what  is going on?

Context:
This is happening inside a foreach loop.
A similar construction outside the loop, `echo $roc_options[0]['class'];` provide similarly nothing.

EDIT

Complete context (lots of debugging crud added to keep me sane)

Code

```
echo "ln1 -- <br>";
   print_r(array_values( $roc_options ));

   echo "<br><br>ln2 -- <br>";
   print_r(array_values( $roc_options[0] ));

   echo "<br><br>ln3a -- <br>";
   echo $roc_options[0]['class']; 

   echo "<br><br>ln3b -- <br>";
   echo $roc_options[0][0]; 


   foreach ( $roc_options as $roc_option ){ 
    echo "<br>inside foreach <br>";

    echo "<br><br>ln4 -- <br>";
    print_r($roc_option);

    echo "<br><br>ln5 -- <br>";
    echo $roc_option[0];
```

output

> ln1 -- Array ( [0] => Array ( ['class'] => classnew1 ['id'] => idnew1
>   ) )
>
> ln2 -- Array ( [0] => classnew1 [1] => idnew1 )
>
> ln3a --
>
> ln3b --
>
> inside foreach
>
> ln4 -- Array ( ['class'] => classnew1 ['id'] => idnew1 )
>
> ln5 --

I cannot understand why 3a, 3b, and 5 are all empty.

---

IT GOES ON AND ON

I switched to var_dumps and forced some new names in, just to make sure the form was saving properly...

CODE:

```
   var_dump($roc_options);
   echo "ln1 -- <br>";
   print_r(array_values( $roc_options ));

   echo "<br><br>ln2 -- <br>";
   print_r(array_values( $roc_options[0] ));

   echo "<br><br>ln3a -- <br>";
   var_dump( $roc_options[0]['class'] ); 

   echo "<br><br>ln3b -- <br>";
   var_dump( $roc_options[0][0]); 


   foreach ( $roc_options as $roc_option ){ 
    echo "<br>inside foreach <br>";

    echo "<br><br>ln4 -- <br>";
    print_r($roc_option);

    echo "<br><br>ln5 -- <br>";
    var_dump( $roc_option[0] );

    echo "<br><br>ln6 -- <br>";
    var_dump( $roc_option['class'] );

    echo "<br><br>ln7 -- <br>";
    var_dump( $roc_option["id"] );
```

output

> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["'class'"]=> string(9) "new class" ["'id'"]=> string(6) "new id" } } 
>   ln1 -- Array ( [0] => Array ( ['class'] => new class ['id'] => new id
>   ) )
>
> ln2 -- Array ( [0] => new class [1] => new id )
>
> ln3a -- NULL
>
> ln3b -- NULL inside foreach
>
> ln4 -- Array ( ['class'] => new class ['id'] => new id )
>
> ln5 -- NULL
>
> ln6 -- NULL
>
> ln6 -- NULL

Notice ln4 ---
$roc_option is an array with two items.
then look at 5-7
I can't get the value out with a numerical index or with a key name, whether in single or double quotes. (When I try without quotes at all, the page doesn't load.)

Comment: Can you post your foreach loop code?

Comment: We need more code to guess where that could come from

Comment: Also your `print_r()` outputs are missing things like commas and quotes  etc and therefore make no sense. Do not edit the output, put it in your question EXACTLY as it appears without any sensorship

Comment: That is EXACTLY how it is outputting. (It may matter that this is inside a WordPress admin page, but I don't see how it should matter. --- I am aware that the output makes no sense. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Try printing stuff out with var_dump when debugging  instead of just plain echo. It will display something even if the value is an empty string, null, a boolean, whatever. And it will also give you the type.

Comment: What type is classnew1? Is it an instance of a class?

Comment: String. These were test names for CSS classes and ids that could be added into a custom options panel. Not that the purpose of any of this is all that relevant.

Comment: The values coming into the array are from a form, the details of which I'm now trying to print back out. And I cannot figure out why I can't access the array values.

Comment: Bet your array doesn't use numeric indexes. It's only printing out numeric indexes cause you're printing it using `array_values`. Use the actual array key to access it. In the foreach, simply do `echo $roc_option['class'];`

Comment: i tried that first and it didn't work. Although, now that I've churned through this a few times, it sorta is. Maybe I'm just going cross-eyed.

Comment: Nope, still not working. Adding to the question....

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump($roc_options);` before ln1 and edit the results into the answer? Should prove enlightening.

Comment: And may want to also put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before ln1

Comment: I added var_dump, with output in question above. I also added in the error reporting, but that did not change output.

Comment: form input was bad - i had single quotes AS PART OF the array value names. so the lesson here is that I'm a goober. THANK YOU ALL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
See difference between `$array['class']` and `$array["'class'"]`

```
foreach ( $options as $optionArray ){ 
    var_dump($optionArray['class']); // notice undefined index
    var_dump($optionArray["'class'"]); // string(9) "classnew1"
}
```

---

You need to make the difference between the output of `array_values` and what `print_r` gives out.

Assuming the following structure, based on your output, see the following logic:

```
$options = array(
    array(
        'class' => 'classnew1',
        'id'    => 'idnew1'
    )
);

print_r($options);

print_r(array_values($options));

print_r(array_values( $options[0] ));

foreach ( $options[0] as $option ){ 
    print $option . PHP_EOL;
}
```

that would print out your inner values.

If you want to extend the loop and not rely on the first index, try this

```
foreach ( $options as $optionArray ){ 
    print $optionArray['class'] . '-' . $optionArray['id']. PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or if you'd like to print out a single value, you could do this

```
print $options[0]['id'];
```

Comment: I know how it should work. Look at the most recent update, though. I just cannot access the values in $roc_option for some reason.

Comment: you have single quotes in your array indexes, I will edit my answer to illustrate. Should have seen it sooner, apologies :)

Comment: oh... wow - those should definitely not be there. I need to go look at my form inputs.

Comment: yeah, they are clearly shown in the output of `print_r` but .. missed them somehow